# Why does my PHP array give me "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"?

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone can help here, I am using an array to get some data split up and on the view this is attached to I get this error above.

here is my code:

PHP for ajax view:

```
$images = array();
  $data_link = array();
  $data_id = array();
  $data_likes = array();
  $data_text = array();
  foreach ($media as $data) {
    //dd($data->caption);
    $images[] = array(
        //dd($data->caption),
        "data_url"=>$data->images->standard_resolution->url,
        "data_link"=>$data->link,
        "data_text" => $data->caption['text'],
        "data_id"=>$data->getId(),
        "data_likes"=>$data->likes->count,
        "data_like"=>$current_user->likes($data),
        "data_token"=>$token

    );
  }
  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->getNextMaxTagId(),
    'images'  => $images
  ));
```

I then access the data with a load more button. When I debug the code for `$data->caption` I get this:

```
object(stdClass)#62 (4) {
  ["created_time"]=>
  string(10) "1377775401"
  ["text"]=>
  string(48) "New arrival #folkclothing reversible knit/jacket"
  ["from"]=>
  object(stdClass)#63 (4) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(18) "vanmildertclothing"
    ["profile_picture"]=>
    string(76) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_24567722_75sq_1342623790.jpg"
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "24567722"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(11) "Van Mildert"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  string(18) "533141169038331174"
}
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

---

Edited below here as the error is not as expected

---

The ajax jquery call for this is as below:

```
  $('#more').click(function() {
    var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
        maxid = $(this).data('maxid');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/ajax',
      data: {
        tag: tag,
        max_tag_id: maxid
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      complete: function(){
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // Output data
        $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
        var $content = $('<article class="instagram-image"><form id="'+ data.images[i].data_token +'" class="forms status-'+ data.images[i].data_like +'" action="'+base+'" method="post"><a class="fancybox" rel="folk-1" href="' + data.images[i].data_url + '"><img alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" src="' + data.images[i].data_url + '" alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" /></a><div class="formSubmit-feedback"></div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+ data.images[i].data_id +'"><p>'+ data.images[i].data_likes +'</p></form></article>');
            var duration = 1000, n = 0.1;
          $content.appendTo('section#images');
          $item = $content.find('form');
          if( $item.hasClass("status-false") ){
                $item.addClass("notLiked");
                //$('.notLiked').find('button.unlike').hide();
                $item.find('a').after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-like like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button>');
            }
            if( $item.hasClass("status-true") ){
                $item.addClass("Liked");
                //$('.Liked').find('button.like').hide();
                $item.find('a').after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-unlike unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>');
            }
          });
        // Store new maxid
        $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
      },
      error:function(){
        $('#error-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
    }
    });
  });
```

On the page I have a button that loads more instagram images into the container, it works okay with everything else but will not work with the caption->text which I am trying to access. If I go to the url /ajax I get the data I want and it shows the text in the text_data array but when it comes to loading that into the images from the load more I get that error.

This is the exact error I get:

`Error rendering view: [instagram.ajax]Trying to get property of non-object`

Not as simple as I first thought.

Comment: Because `caption` is not an array, your dump tells you it's an object of `stdClass` and that it has property called `text`. It's not `$data->caption['text']`, it's `$data->caption->text`. Basically, you had to read the error and understand it. You tried to use object as an array. Error tells you can't use object as an array. You ignored it, and went to ask the question, therefore I'll downvote you for lack of trying, it's really a trivial error and basic of basics

Comment: wow, okay! Thanks for your straight honesty. The issue is not as straight as that because with that I get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`. I am accessing the url through an ajax call and when I inspect the network tab for the call I get an error and through investigation it throws that error.

Comment: Well, now you've arrived at a different problem and should probably include everything you're trying to do so we can actually help you instead of criticise :) the error that you initially got was because you tread object as array. Now, you've mentioned something else. Mind including all of your steps so we can also see what's going on and where it goes wrong?

Comment: Okay keep an eye out for the new edited version cheers :)

Answer (score 7):

Exactly as it says: `$data->caption` is an *object*, but you're trying to access it like an array using `$data->caption['text']`. Access it like an object instead:

```
$data->caption->text
```

Comment: I get this error in the network preview area: `Trying to get property of non-object` because I am using an ajax call to access the data with a click to load more button, this uses the /ajax url with `"data_text" => $data->caption->text` in it.

Comment: Well, now you're trying to access something like an object *which is not an object*. Same thing in reverse.

Comment: hmm, what would the solution be to this?

Comment: The solution is: don't do that. :P I mean, it's certainly not the same piece of data it was complaining about the first time. Either it's a completely different case where this is happening, or you have data which is sometimes an object and sometimes maybe nothing. Then you need to either make sure your data isn't mixed or you check first whether something exists or not before trying to access it.

Answer (score 5):

`$data->caption` is an object but your code is trying to access it as if it were an array.

Change `$data->caption['text']` to `$data->caption->text`

Comment: Upvoted, seems like someone was on downvote spree for no reason.

Comment: That was not me by the way!!

Answer (score 3):

`$data->caption` is an object, and you are accessing it as an array.

Use `$data->caption->text` instead.

Comment: I also got downvoted for no reason. +1. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Right the answer was this:

```
foreach ($media as $data) {
    $title = (isset($data->caption))?mb_substr($data->caption->text,0,70,"utf8"):null;
    $images[] = array(
        "data_url"=>$data->images->standard_resolution->url,
        "data_link"=>$data->link,
        "data_text" => htmlspecialchars($title),
        "data_id"=>$data->getId(),
        "data_likes"=>$data->likes->count,
        "data_like"=>$current_user->likes($data),
        "data_token"=>$token

    );
  }
```

So I declared the variable before the images array and then accessed it in the array.